# Como alinhar um elemento na parte de baixo da div mãe?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Eu preciso que o conteúdo que está no `<h1>` fique alinhado abaixo (*bottom*) na `<div>`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="inline m-3">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" width="100px">
  </div>
  <div class="inline m-3">
    <h1>Título</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Estou usando Bootstrap 4.1 e segui o conteúdo da [documentação](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/vertical-align/), mas sem sucesso.
Acredito que deve ser simples, mas ainda não entendi o conceito por traz disso.

Comment: Tentou colocar o class="align-bottom" dentro do H1 ?

Comment: Adicione os seguintes atributos no style do seu h1: position: absolute; bottom:0;

Comment: Já sim. Essa solução é mostrado no link que anexei a minha pergunta

Comment: Tem várias formas de fazer, detalhe melhor a pergunta. O que você quer é, somente que o `div` que tem o `h1` fique embaixo do primeiro `div`?

Comment: Não, eu quero que o h1 fique alinhado ao lado da imagem e alinhado abaixo(bottom)

Comment: esse alinhado abaixo seria no rodapé?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trabalhe com [flexbox](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/).
Você pode alinhar isoladamente um elemento por meio da propriedade [`align-self`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#align-self):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class='d-flex'>
  <img src='http://lorempixel.com/160/160/abstract/'>
  <div class='d-flex mx-2'>
    <h1 class='align-self-end'>Título</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfeito... Não conhecia as classes 'flex'. Mais uma coisa prendida sobre bootstrap. Obrigado.